# When overloading operator << inside a class, why I must declare it as a friend function despite the fact that it is already declared inside the class?

Tags: c++, oop, vector, operator-overloading, friend

I am trying to overload operator '<<' inside a class, but it's a must to declare it as a *friend* function otherwise the compiler would through into error: *binary'operator<<' has too many parameters*
This is my function prototype:

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& sout, const SimpleVector v);
```

I understand that *friend* function is used if I want to implement the function outside the class and access non-public class member, but this time I am implementing the function inside the class why do I need to use *friend* keyword

Comment: Inside class you don't pass an object since you know object from "this" pointer (unless it is static).

Comment: If `ostream` is a class you created, you may define your `operator<<` in that class without making it a `friend`.  You only need to make that function a friend if you are defining it inside some other class.  If your `ostream` is actually `std::ostream`, for example, you can not edit that class.

Comment: Declared inside a class, a function could be a *member* function, a *class* function (i.e., `static`), or a *freestanding function that additionally has access to private and protected members* (i.e., `friend`).  A **binary operator** overload member function has the implied `this` parameter as the first "parameter".

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to define the stream operator inside your class you need to omit the argument `const SimpleVector v` because it is already in the `this` pointer. However with that you cannot use the operator as usual (because of missing [uniform function call syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Function_Call_Syntax)):

`std::cout << SimpleVector() << std::endl;`

because this calls the free function

```
operator<<(std::ostream&, const SimpleVector);
```

You would need to call the member function in a cumbersome way:

```
SimpleVector v;
v.operator<<(std::cout) << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Npn-static member functions are considered to have an extra parameter, called the implicit object parameter, which represents the object for which member functions have been called. There is a convention that the implicit object parameter, if present, is always the first parameter and the implied object argument, if present, is always the first argument.

So this declaration within a class

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& sout, const SimpleVector v);
```

implies that the function has three parameters while the overloaded `operator <<` is a binary operator.

When such a function is declared as a friend function then neither implicit parameter that refers to an object of a class is present.

> I understand that friend function is used if I want to implement the
> function outside the class

You may implement a friend function within a class definition.

Functions are declared as friend functions to make it possible to access private and protected members of classes within friend functions.